# Using batch file menu to choose which further batch to run

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I followed [this neat tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/78083-batch-files-create-menu-execute-commands.html) and tried editing it for my use.

I came to a little problem creating a small batch file with a little menu where after choosing an option ( e.g. RUN ARMA3DB ) it would call a :ARMA3DB script within the batch, which would start the desired batch file that runs a file called A3DB-V2.bat ( located elsewhere ).

```
ECHO OFF
CLS

:MENU
cls
ECHO.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO.
ECHO  1 - RUN - ArmA 3 Server
ECHO  2 - RUN - ArmA 3 Database
ECHO  3 - RUN - Minecraft Server
ECHO  4 - RUN - Killing Floor Server
ECHO  5 - RUN - Insurgency Server
ECHO  6 - RUN - Starbound Server
ECHO  7 - EXIT
ECHO.

SET /P M=Type 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, or 7 then press ENTER:

IF %M%==1 GOTO ARMA3SERVER
IF %M%==2 GOTO ARMA3DB
IF %M%==3 GOTO MINECRAFT
IF %M%==4 GOTO KILLINGFLOOR2 
IF %M%==5 GOTO INSURGENCY
IF %M%==6 GOTO STARBOUND
IF %M%==7 GOTO EOF

:ARMA3SERVER
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Arma 3\"
start A3-V2.bat
GOTO MENU

:ARMA3DB
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Arma 3\DB\"
start A3DB-V2.bat
GOTO MENU

:MINECRAFT
cd "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\McMyAdmin\"
start McMyAdmin-V2.bat
GOTO MENU

:KILLINGFLOOR2
cd "C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\killingfloor2\"
start KF2ServerReunion-V2.bat
GOTO MENU

:INSURGENCY
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Insurgency Dedicated Server\"
start Insurgency-V2.bat
GOTO MENU

:STARBOUND
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Starbound\win64\"
start starbound_server-v2.bat
GOTO MENU
```

This is in the A3DB-V2.bat:

```
START /min redis-server.exe redis.conf
```

The problem is when I call the option "2" for ARMA3DB, the desired batch file (A3DB-V2.bat) opens the native console for the program "redist-server.exe" BUT it also opens an entire new cmd tab with:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Arma 3\DB\START /min redist-server.exe redist.conf
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Arma 3\DB>
```

I tried working around it by adding /B (for not opening a new cmd tab) after START command in the script in the menu batch like so:

```
:ARMA3DB
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Arma 3\DB\"
start /B A3DB-V2.cmd
GOTO MENU
```

But a new problem popped up, now it shows the same thing but in the same tab as the menu is in. So:

```
Type 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, or 7 then press ENTER:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Arma 3\DB\START /min redist-server.exe redist.conf
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Arma 3\DB>
```

So I can't enter any further value, It seems like it ignored the GOTO MENU, and instead it continued as a new instance of cmd.exe in the folder where it started the new batch file.

Does anyone please has an idea for a simple work-around option so I could just open the menu.bat file, choose an option, press enter, which could run the desired batch file ( minimized ) and that I could immediately choose another option from the same menu file afterwards?

// The script is not entirely complete of course, I got stuck on this one problem.

Thanks for all eventual replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CALL` command for calling other batch files. For example, change this code:

```
:ARMA3SERVER
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Arma 3\"
start A3-V2.bat
GOTO MENU
```

To this:

```
:ARMA3SERVER
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Arma 3\"
call A3-V2.bat
GOTO MENU
```

Then add `@` to each called Batch File like this: `@START /min redis-server.exe redis.conf` so that it will run with `@echo` set to off.

Comment: So all this time I've had to set the echo state before and after a start, i could've just added a hide symbol to the command itself? Damn i should've expected that behavior . . .